# Open new window after splash window in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I have three window which suppose to come in this order:

1. Splash window
2. Selection window
3. Working window, this is main window

splash window should appear for 3 seconds and I have done it like this way and it's working fine:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        loadingThread = new Thread(load);
        loadingThread.Start();
    }


private void load()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);  
        //close the window

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate() { Close(); });

    }
```

After that selection window should appear and after that working window should come.

Mainwindow code is here:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(this);
        base.DataContext = this.mainWindowViewModel;
        SplashWindow wnd = new SplashWindow("text");
        wnd.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

Tell me how can I open my window in that sequence

and one more thing on selection window, I have one button after pressing that my working window should come.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Without using `async` & `await`

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        // Create and show SplashWindow
        SplashWindow splashWindow = new SplashWindow();
        splashWindow.Show();


        var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(p =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                // Create and show the SelectionWindow
                SelectionWindow selectionWindow = new SelectionWindow();
                selectionWindow.Show();

                // Hide the SplashWindow we previosly created
                splashWindow.Close();
            });
        });

        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Gist with sample application: [click here](https://gist.github.com/Jossef/c6de37e25bbaeaa7e029)

---

I'm assuming that this is your project's structure:

1. App.xaml
2. MainWindow
3. SelectionWindow
4. SplashWindow

first, on your `App.xaml`, remove `StartupUri` attribute so it will look like:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication2.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then, on your `App.xaml.cs`, override `OnStartup`:

```
async protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    // Create and show SplashWindow
    SplashWindow splashWindow = new SplashWindow();
    splashWindow.Show();

    // Let's wait 3 seconds
    await Task.Delay(3000);

    // Create and show the SelectionWindow
    SelectionWindow selectionWindow = new SelectionWindow();
    selectionWindow.Show();

    // Hide the SplashWindow we previosly created
    splashWindow.Close();
}
```

Then, in your `SelectionWindow`, add a button with a click event:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create and show MainWindow
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.Show();

    // Closes SelectionWindow
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hi......I have VS2010 where It don't support async and await. Please can you give answer where no need to use async and await. Thansk for your reply.